# App clip size too big for react-native app

Tags: react-native, size, ipa, apple-appclips

We have a react native app. Now we are trying to fit app clip into it. The issue we are facing is with the package.json file. The app requires a lot of packages that the app clip does not, but due to a single package.json file, the appclip size is getting bloated up unnecessarily. Has anyone faced this issue before? Is there a way to minimize this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and what I did is to skip the native libraries for the app clip iOS target in Podfile using this technique: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1179#issuecomment-756539463